# Trouble getting Bootstrap to work

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to use the bootstrap carousel on my website, but only the first picture shows. The arrows and toggle buttons on the button will not switch to the second or third photo. The error in the console says 'file not found'.

I'm not sure what I'm missing and it's driving me crazy. Any help would be appreciated as I'm sure it's a quick and relatively easy thing I'm missing... Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/EM1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/EM2.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/EM3.jpg" alt="..">
            <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us any of your code? Are you sure that the second and third photo file names are written without any typos*, and the files actually exist in the expected locations? * just yesterday I confused myself with an accidental space after an underscore, which was hard to notice and caused an image to not show up.

Comment: just fixed it to show, sorry about that! all spelling is correct as far as I can see regarding the img src

Comment: Have you checked your console for any errors since this requires jquery and bootstrapjs to function.

Answer (score 0):

here the working carousel code of bootstrap
`file not found` error comes when you attached incorrectly. so it would be better that you **start coding again** this snippet is working i hope it helps.

```css
h2{
    margin: 0;     
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 90px;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-family: "trebuchet ms", sans-serif;    
}

.item{
    background: white;    
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px !important;
}

.carousel{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bs-example{
 margin: 20px;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .item {
  opacity:0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* ie fix */
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.item {
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* ie fix */
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Carousel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="6500" data-ride="carousel">
     <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>   
       <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 1</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>First slide label</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 2</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                  <p>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 3</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                  <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked. My linking to Bootstrap was off. Thanks !